# ¿Cómo puedo verificar que haya algún dato en un archivo?

Tags: dev-c++

Básicamente estoy haciendo que se ingresen nombres a tal archivo, y por lo visto, mi maestro quiere que si no existe ningún dato(nombre) en el archivo, que no se ejecute. Solo me falta eso

```
        FILE*arkLista = fopen("siu.txt", "wt");//Crear archivo
```

Comment: Lee el archivo y si no tiene contenido, es que no tiene datos.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.